# Different labels for the same series

Tags: c#, charts

I'm not very sure if my question title makes much sense? But basically what I'm trying to do is show the value of each column in the chart.

Here's what i'm trying to do:

[image]

So I have 2 variables `first_AverageOnTime` and `second_AverageOnTime`. Ideally I would want to have the label for `M` on the chart be the first and label for `A` for second.

So the code I'm using is

```
LeChart.Series.Add("Average On Time");
LeChart.Series["Average On Time"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

LeChart.Series.Add("Average On %");
LeChart.Series["Average On %"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

LeChart.Series.Add("Average Off %");
LeChart.Series["Average Off %"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

LeChart.Series.Add("Peak Hour");
LeChart.Series["Peak Hour"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;

LeChart.Series["Average On Time"].Points.AddXY("M", a_AverageLightONTime);
LeChart.Series["Average On Time"].Label = first_AverageLightONTime.ToString();
LeChart.Series["Average On %"].Points.AddXY("M", a_PercentLightOn);
LeChart.Series["Average Off %"].Points.AddXY("M", a_PercentLightOff);
LeChart.Series["Peak Hour"].Points.AddXY("M", a_PeakHour);

LeChart.Series["Average On Time"].Points.AddXY("A", b_AverageLightONTime);
LeChart.Series["Average On Time"].Label = second_AverageLightONTime.ToString();
LeChart.Series["Average On %"].Points.AddXY("A", b_PercentLightOn);
LeChart.Series["Average Off %"].Points.AddXY("A", b_PercentLightOff);
LeChart.Series["Peak Hour"].Points.AddXY("A", b_PeakHour);
```

`a_AverageLightONTime` and `b_AverageLightONTime` has the same values as `first_AverageOnTime` and `second_AverageOnTime`
Any ideas? Also I'm using the standard `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;`.

Comment: You need to share more code of how are you setting Series and binding data to the char.

Comment: What charting framework is this?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Okay so basically I'm doing everything programmatically and I've also edited my question :)  And... I'm using the standard visual studio chart, torsan

Comment: @GrantWinney okay so `a_AverageLightOnTime` & `b_AverageLightOnTime` has the same value as `first_AverageLightONTime` and `second_AverageLightONTime`

Comment: Can't you label the data point: e.g. something like this: `Chart1.Series["Average On Time etc etc"].Label = "Y = #VALY\nX = #VALX";`              (you'll have to stub in the actual values of the variables you'll be using)

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Yes, but the whole point of this question is to have the `M` columns display the first value and `A` column display second value.